# Eloquent relation condition 2 columns foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have case like this

table **transactions**

> |id|account_from_id|account_to_id|value|

table **account**

> |id|name|type|

I would like to use eloquent relation from table account to transaction which is it need additional condition, account as **from**, or account as **to**, but in one function only relation

this is my code

```
public function transactions(){
    $result = $this->hasOne('App\Transactions','id', 'account_from_id');
    if(!is_null($result)){
        return $result;
    }

    return $this->hasOne('App\Transactions','id' 'account_to_id');
}
```

But it not work as I expected, when account as **to**, it will return null

Answer (score 1):

The model column has a relation must be define on reference table and column
make each column has a relation on your model

```
public function account_from(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\Transactions','id', 'account_from_id');
}
public function account_to(){
   $this->hasOne('App\Transactions','id', 'account_to_id');
}
```

define the account transaction by the new transaction attribute

```
public function getTransactionAttribute(){
   if(!empty($this->account_from_id)){
       return $this->account_from
   }else{
       return $this->account_to
   }
}
```

Comment: This will showing error when I declare relation variable.

 echo $this->transaction->name;

because it will eager loading the 2 table from $this->account_from and $this->account_to, but the problem is only one of them that has the relation

Comment: if it call only one of rows. you can using return $this->belongsTo on functiont account_from and account_to. $this->hasOne will be return as array